# iPhone 5s and Premiere Pro Cs6

Tags: youtube, sync, adobe, iphone

Using an iPhone 5s to film short talks, I run the video files thru Handbrake to settle sync issues that arise when I upload videos into Premiere Pro Cs6. Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem, it simply minimizes it. Suggestions?

Comment: Welcome Laurel :) Please start with the tour: http://video.stackexchange.com/tour to get familiar with video.se. For a solid answer please specify your question a bit and try to explain what are your _sync issues_. Anyway, enjoy the site!